# can Kafka connect value conveter (JSONConverter) can be used to convert GPB?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

can Kafka connect value conveter (JSONConverter) can be used to convert GPB ?

I am using kafka connect as sink and writing all topic messages (GPB) into database

I am using default JSONConverter as valueconverter in value.converter field in property file, can this be used to convert GPB object ?

If not can I use the deserializer class used to this deserialize this object or I need to write some other custom class? could you please share some example of the same

Answer (score 2):

No, the JSONConverter expects strictly-formatted JSON, Protocol Buffers (I assume that's what you mean by GPB?) are binary records and need an appropriate converter.

Fortunately the community has one available here: https://github.com/blueapron/kafka-connect-protobuf-converter/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yeah i have read about this but was just thinking if we could use any of the already available converter within kafka lib. Is it supported by confluent or its third party?

Comment: it's a community converter, but it's the right one to use if you're trying to use protobuf with Kafka Connect.